# Line on some browsers

Tags: html, css

There is a line that appears under the text in a certain div.

The problem only appears on only Firefox and IE.

Here are screen shots, I am using the entire div as a link:

[image]

[image]

Here is how I have built the divs and text

In the css:

```
.whiteTextBold {
    color:#fff;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.moreInfo {
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.0);
    border:1px solid;
    border-color:#fff;
    width:170px;
    height:35px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

in the file:

```
<a target="_blank" href="#">
<div class="moreInfo">
<table width="100%" height="100%">
<tr><td align="center"><font class="whiteTextBold">More info</font></td></tr>
</table>
</div></a>
```

What can I do to avoid having this line?

Comment: Just a side note, you're using deprecated elements and attributes with `<font>` and `align="center"`.

Comment: thank you, how is it done now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

or add a class to the a's if you already have a style for them.